# How do I reference this sheet using an index instead of the worksheet name?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

See the code snippet below. I'm basically just looking for how I might select the same sheet Previous Month without using a hardcoded name.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]Previous Month'!R4C4+RC[-4]"
```

I tried it this way once and it didn't seem to work for me:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]'(1)!R4C4+RC[-4]"
```

Error: [Error I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ1hC.png)

Any thoughts? I just don't want to have to manually type in Previous Month for the worksheet name if I can help it, would rather reference it with an index.

Per requests I added a little bit more code and the error. I'm trying not to add the full code because the full code is extremely long, does multiple things, and I don't want to distract from the main reason I asked this question.

```
Sheets("Month Raw Data").Select
Range("H4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]Previous Month'!R4C8+RC[-4]"
Range("H4").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("H5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]Previous Month'!R5C8+RC[-4]"
Range("H5").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("J4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(((RC[-2]-RC[-1])/RC[-1])*100)"
Range("J5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(((RC[-2]-RC[-1])/RC[-1])*100)"
Range("H8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]Previous Month'!R8C8+RC[-4]"
Range("H9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]Previous Month'!R9C8+RC[-4]"
Range("H10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]Previous Month'!R10C8+RC[-4]"
Range("H11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]Previous Month'!R11C8+RC[-4]"
Range("H8").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("H4:H5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("H14").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]Previous Month'!R14C8+RC[-4]"
Range("H15").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]Previous Month'!R15C8+RC[-4]"
Range("H17").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]Previous Month'!R17C8+RC[-4]"
Sheets("Month % Change").Select
Range("I29").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]Previous Month'!R[-26]C[8]+RC[-5]"
Range("I29").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I29:I50")
Range("I29:I49").Select
Range("I29:I50").Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: Use a worksheet variable, e.g. `ws`, and concatenate in the `.Name`?

Comment: If you want to use an index, assuming the previous month is always the 2nd last sheet you could get the index number by `Worksheets.Count - 1`

Comment: So the sheet name Previous Month is the only sheet in the workbook. That's why I thought replacing it with the index (1) might work. I'm getting an object error though.

Comment: Care to share? *I'm getting an object error though* ...

Comment: A little more of your code would be very helpful here

Comment: I think I've added as much as I can. I've added the error and more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

```
dim WksName as string

WksName = Workbooks("Previous Month''s Public Numbers").sheets(1).Name    '1 is the indice you want

'Now you call the sheet in all your formula this way :
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='[Previous Month''s Public Numbers.xls]" & WksName & "'!R[-26]C[8]+RC[-5]"
```

I hope I understood you well.